# Python 2to3 adding extra parenthesis around functional argument

Tags: python, python-2to3

I'm a bit baffled why `2to3` is bothering embracing my print arguments that are already in functional style to be wrapped in an extra set of parenthesis. For example

```
print("\t[Warn] Can not connect {}".format(ssid))
```

becomes

```
print(("\t[Warn] Can not connect {}".format(ssid)))
```

Are these essentially conservative false positives? I'm thinking maybe the trailing `)` in the format function is throwing its logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation

> When the -p is passed, 2to3 treats print as a function instead of a statement. This is useful when from **future** import print_function is being used. If this option is not given, the print fixer will surround print calls in an extra set of parentheses because it cannot differentiate between the print statement with parentheses (such as print ("a" + "b" + "c")) and a true function call.

[2to3 Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html)